# Составить regex с исключением для поиска ссылок и ссылок в тегах html?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста составить regex для следующего правила.
Мне нужно найти все ссылки на внешние ресурсы (ссылки как чистый текст так и в тегах) кроме указанного домена example123.com

Пример, каждая строка ниже должна быть захвачена регуляркой

```
http://domain.com/
domain.com
<a href="http://domain.com/article/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1">...</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/article/">...</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/article/">...</a>
<img href="http://domain.com/article/Кошка Собака.png">
<link href="http://domain.com/">
<area href="http://domain.com/">
<base href="http://domain.com/">
```

А вот эти строки должны быть пропущены так как в них есть разрешенный домен example123.com

```
http://example123.com
example123.com
<a href="http://example123.com/article/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1">...</a>
<a href="http://example123.com/article/">...</a>
<a href="http://example123.com/article/">...</a>
<img href="http://example123.com/article/Кошка Собака.png">
<link href="http://example123.com/">
<area href="http://example123.com/">
<base href="http://example123.com/">
```

А так же относительный ссылки должны быть пропущены

```
<a href="images/xxx.jpg">
```

Я сосбвтенно пробывал объединять и эксперементировать с двумя шаблонами

```
((https?:\/\/)?([\w-]{1,32}\.[\w-]{1,32})[^\s@]*)
/(<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>)/m
```

Но так и не смог добится нужного эффекта, то ссылки не все находит, то лишние тэги захватывает, то на оборот не захватывает. Поэтому прошу помощи у знающих людей.
https://regex101.com/r/qelZG0/1

**UPDATE**: Сейчас остановился на такой регулярки, но почему то захватывает локальные ссылки

```
<(.*?)(href=")((https?:\/\/[^example123.com])?([\w-]{1,32}\.[\w-]{1,32})[^\s@]*)(.*?>)
```

**UPDATE2**

> <(.*?)(href=")((https?://(?!example123.com))?([\w-]{1,32}.[\w-]{1,32})[^\s@]*)(.*?)(<.*?>|.*?>)

**UPDATE3**
Остановился на [этом](https://regex101.com/r/oM45cH/1) вроде похоже на правду, но ни как не могу избавится от захвата строки

```
<p> <a href="tip.html">Как сделать такое же фото?</a>
```

Почему то захватывается тэг *p* и ссылка хотя не должна.

Comment: [html не получится парсить регулярными выражениями](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить URL ссылки кроме ссылок на домен подойдет [такая регулярка](https://regex101.com/r/6loCC1/1):

```
(((?:")(https?:\/\/)(?!example123\.com)[^"]+(?:"))|((https?:\/\/)(?!example123\.com)[^\s"]+))
```

Она захватывает только если есть http://, но без него это не было бы ссылкой.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, работает идеально!